# Quandl request does not deliver the actual data

Tags: c#, api, quandl

I am currently writing a request to the Quandl API using [HubertJ's QuandlCS C#-Wrapper](https://github.com/HubertJ/QuandlCS) to receive EUR-USD rates, my code is as follows:

```
QuandlDownloadRequest request = new QuandlDownloadRequest();
request.Datacode = new Datacode("ECB", "EURUSD");
request.Format = FileFormats.JSON;
request.Frequency = Frequencies.Daily;
request.Truncation = 100;
request.Sort = SortOrders.Ascending;
request.Transformation = Transformations.None;
request.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
request.StartDate = request.StartDate.AddMinutes(-5);
request.EndDate = DateTime.Now;

IQuandlConnection connection = new QuandlConnection();
string data = connection.Request(request);
```

But I only receive following output:

> {"errors":{},"id":14686248,"source_name":"European Central Bank","source_code":"ECB","code":"EURUSD","name":"EUR vs USD Foreign Exchange Reference Rate","urlize_name":"EUR-vs-USD-Foreign-Exchange-Reference-Rate","display_url":"https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/eurofxref-graph-usd.en.html","description":"Euro (EUR) vs. US Dollar (USD) reference exchange rate. Foreign exchange reference rates are published by the European Central Bank.  Reference rates are usually updated by 3:00pm CET, based on a regular daily concertation procedure between various central banks across Europe and around the world.  This procedure normally takes place at 2:15pm CET.  Reference rates are mid-market rates, calculated as averages of the buying and selling rate; they do not necessarily reflect actual transaction rates.  Euro foreign exchange reference rates are always quoted using the 'certain' method (i.e EUR 1 = X foreign currency units, where X is the published reference rate).","updated_at":"2018-11-16T23:15:43.248Z","frequency":"daily","from_date":"1999-01-04","to_date":"2018-11-16","column_names":["Date","Value"],"premium":false,"data":[],"type":"Time Series"}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the API changed.

```
API v1
API v3

https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/ECB/EURUSD.json?collapse=daily&transformation=none&sort_order=asc&rows=100&trim_start=2018-11-18&trim_end=2018-11-19
https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/ECB/EURUSD/data.json?collapse=daily&transform=none&order=asc&start_date=2018-11-18&end_date=2018-11-19

.json
/data.json

transformation
transform

sort_order
order

trim_start
start_date

trim_end
end_date
```

By changing the field-names and some modifications it worked.